# Why i am getting these errors while using rspec to test models in ruby and rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

```
1) RfidT is not valid without device_mac 
     Failure/Error: expect(obj2.errors[:device_mac]).to include ("not valid without device_mac!")
       expected [] to include "not valid without device_mac!"
     # ./spec/models/rfid_t_spec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) RfidT  duplicate values of epc are not allowed
     Failure/Error: expect(obj3.errors[:epc]).to include("duplicate values of epc are not allowed!")
       expected [] to include "duplicate values of epc are not allowed!"
     # ./spec/models/rfid_t_spec.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) RfidT is not valid without first_seen 
     Failure/Error: expect(obj4.errors[:first_seen]).to include("cannot be Blank!")
       expected ["can't be blank"] to include "cannot be Blank!"
     # ./spec/models/rfid_t_spec.rb:33:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) RfidT is not valid without last_seen 
     Failure/Error: expect(obj5.errors[:last_seen]).to include("cannot be Blank!")
       expected ["can't be blank"] to include "cannot be Blank!"
     # ./spec/models/rfid_t_spec.rb:39:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.16685 seconds (files took 6.45 seconds to load)
6 examples, 4 failures
```

But when i am using to_not in place of to in spec file then i am not getting any error .Please tell me what is meaning of this and what is the diffrence between to and to_not in ruby and rails.

my spec file generating no error is:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe RfidT, type: :model do
   it "is valid without epc,device_mac,first_seen,last_seen,count" do
             obj=RfidT.new(epc:"abc",device_mac:"pqrs",first_seen:10,last_seen:20,count:200)
             expect(obj).to be_valid
 end

 it "is not valid without epc" do
                      obj1=RfidT.new(epc:nil)
                      obj1.valid?
                      #expect(obj1.errors[:epc]).to include("cannot be Blank!")
                      expect(obj1).to_not be_valid

 end

 it"is not valid without device_mac " do
             obj2=RfidT.new(device_mac:nil)
             obj2.valid?
             expect(obj2.errors[:device_mac]).to_not include ("not valid without device_mac!")
 end

 it" duplicate values of epc are not allowed" do
                       RfidT.create(epc:"abc",device_mac:"pqrs",first_seen:10,last_seen:20,count:200)
                       obj3=RfidT.new(epc:"abc",device_mac:"pqrs",first_seen:10,last_seen:20,count:200)
                       obj3.valid?
                       expect(obj3.errors[:epc]).to_not include("duplicate values of epc are not allowed!")

 end
 it "is not valid without first_seen " do
             obj4=RfidT.new(first_seen:nil)
                      obj4.valid?
                      expect(obj4.errors[:first_seen]).not_to include("cannot be Blank!")
 end

  it "is not valid without last_seen " do
             obj5=RfidT.new(last_seen:nil)
                      obj5.valid?
                      expect(obj5.errors[:last_seen]).to_not include("cannot be Blank!")
 end
end
```

Comment: any method that ends in a ? is supported by rSpec.  You should be able to change to include to read "to_include" and  it should just work.

Comment: its giving me  NoMethodError when i change to include to to_include.

Comment: What is difference when i use to and to_not?

Comment: I'm confused. What part exactly of `expected ["can't be blank"] to include "cannot be Blank!"` is not unclear to you?

Comment: Actually i am beginner to ROR and i am not getting why expect(obj).to include(msg) is giving failures and expect (obj) to_not include(msg) not?

Answer (score 1):

`to` checks that the matcher (the thing that follows) matches, for example

```
expect(obj).to be_valid
```

Checks that `obj.valid?` is truthy. If it isn't the example will be mark as failed.

`to_not` is the opposite: it checks that the matcher doesn't match. In the above example it will mark the example as failed if `obj.valid?` is truthy.

Unless your code raises an exception, one of `to` or `to_not` will pass, because they are opposites of each other.

Your rspec output is telling you that your validations are not enforcing the constraints you want them to.

Comment: should i mention .rb file for this model?

Comment: what should i do to make them run? how should i pass all tests?